# SDKs for Data Matrix scanning in iOS

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner

I'm building an app where I need a barcode scanning module. The barcodes my system has are always 2D Data Matrix. Now I've been looking for some SDKs which can help but so far haven't found much.

I already use ZXing for my android app, but they have pulled plug for iOS.

iOS itself has a barcode reading module but it does not list 2D data matrix as a supported code type.

ZBar is another solution, but it too doesn't scan 2D data matrix.

Do you know a SDK perhaps that I can use ?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for those looking for the answer as of today...as of iOS 8 this included in the AVFoundation. see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Machine_Readable_Object_Types